# How do I add a view exposed filter on a node reference field?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view on a book node that has many different fields; one of them is the Author field, which is a node reference to the node's author.
I would like to build a search view for books adding some parameters, one of which is a text field for the author name.

Is there a way to create an exposed filter on a node reference field? I've not found a way.

Comment: I'm not sure. You want the exposed filters in the form node/add/book or when you see the content? Oskar

Comment: No,i want the exposed filter on a View that shows the Books content type

Comment: @OskarCalvo: I want it on the node/add/book. How can that be done? is it possible?